# How can I use (Go) yq to reduce a YAML document to a desired set of keys and produce a CSV?

Tags: csv, yaml, yq

I have the following YAML document:

```
222:
  description:
    en: "124098-en"
    fr: "498438-fr"
  name:
    en: "293878-en"
    fr: "222493878-fr"
  mass: 0.1
  groupID: "24902"
223:
  description:
    en: "124098-en"
    fr: "498438-fr"
  name:
    en: "zz325-en"
    fr: "222493878-fr"
  mass: 0.1
  groupID: "234988"
[many other records]
```

I would like to construct a CSV that looks like:

```
222,"293878-en","24902"
223,"zz325-en","234988"
```

That is, each row is just:

- first field: the key of the map in the original document
- second field: the `.[].name.en` from the original document
- third field: the `.[].groupID` from the original document

No other fields are preserved in the CSV from the original document.

What's the right way to do this?

**Addendum:** I'm using the Go version of yq (4.7.1) but either the Go or the Python version is fine, or if that's not the right tool here, I'm happy to use something else.

Comment: Mandatory question on `yq` tagged questions - Do you have the Python or the Go version installed?

Comment: @Inian: Edited! Happy to use either; right now I have the Go version (4.7.1).

Comment: Also `groupID` is not a string, is it intentional to have it in quotes?

Comment: Ah, you're right, that's not clear in the example. It's not a string in the two specific keys there, but it could be in general, and it often is in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `yq` version is much more straightforward to use, because it literally uses `jq` under the hood to operate on the JSON converted from the YAML.

You can use the `jq`'s constructs and get the CSV result as

```
yq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | [ ($k|tonumber), (.[$k] | .name.en, .groupID) ] | @csv' yaml
```

The `@csv` function puts the elements collected in the array to the native type as originally encoded in the source. If `groupID` is intended to be stored as a string, it could be done as `.groupID | tostring`

---

Go `yq` was much unique prior to v4, when it used its own DSL, but now as of `v4.8` its trying so hard to implement the functions of `jq`. It doesn't have a CSV function out-of-the-box yet.

Comment: Thank you! This worked splendidly, and you're right, it's definitely easier to use the Python `yq`.

Answer (score 5):

Latest version of `yq` (4.16+) now has the '@csv' operator

```sh
yq e '.[] | [key, .name.en, .groupID] | @csv' file.yaml
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: note that the underlying csv encoder will automatically wrap strings in quotes if required (e.g. they have a comma in them).